# Multiblock Module D7 $edit

Tags: 7, blocks

Using the multiblock module, I haven't been able to retrieve the $edit variable my custom `hook_block_configure()` or `hook_block_view()`. According to the readme:

`add an optional $edit
argument to your hook_block_view and hook_block_configure functions.`

I have, like so:

`function donation_form_block_configure($delta = '', $edit = array()) { ... }`

But alas, $edit is all ways null. I'm simply looking for the multiblock id during the configuration and viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the module aint workin.

hacked it to fix.

```
$block = module_invoke($block_info->module, 'block_'. $op, $block_info->orig_delta, $edit);
```

Comment: i did the same but still the $edit comes as null in "Configure' and Save ops.
Any idea?